# Xcode / Objective-C - log which class you're in

Tags: objective-c, class, debugging, methods, lldb

Is there a way, using Xcode in Objective-C, to log which the class and method you're in?

I'm aware you can add a `%B` to a breakpoint to show the method and class but the problem with that is you're having to guess which class you're in, add the breakpoints, then disable them.

What I'd like to do is add a breakpoint in Xcode with some command that echoes the current class/object and method to the console.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. When do you want to log? How "are you in" a class?

Comment: *controller or class*. Controller are (instances of) classes

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",[self className]);

Comment: You can put `NSLog(@"%@ %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd))` wherever you need to log something.  If you have a bug, and you don't know where the code is for the thing that is exhibiting the bug, it's kind of up to you to figure it out.  You could log every method call.  If you give more details, we may be able to suggest other strategies.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: but `[self class]` is not necessarily the class "you're in" in the code

Comment: @newacct that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: The OP wants to know the class in the source code the method is in. That is very different from the runtime class of the object pointed to by `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a method, the built-in identifier `__func__` expands to a C string containing the class name and method name. So:

```
NSLog(@"currently executing %s", __func__);
```

Example output:

```
2015-03-10 13:30:46.085 border[33025:4276130] currently executing -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
```